# Passagem de parâmetros duplos para o Jasper report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Estou fazendo um relatório que passa como parâmetros:
Data inicial, data final e tipo (que pode ser: entrada, saída ou entrada e saída).

Tudo funciona bem até eu tentar obter o relatório que pega entrada e saída... já tentei de muitas formas e não consigo resultados.

Query no Jasper.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código Java:

```
protected void relEntrada(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try{
        SessionImplementor sim = (SessionImplementor) HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Connection con = sim.connection();

        String tipoMov = request.getParameter("tipMov");

        String dataini = request.getParameter("dataini");
        String dtini[] = dataini.split("/");
        String diai = dtini[0];
        String mesi = dtini[1];
        String anoi = dtini[2];

        String datafim = request.getParameter("datafim");
        String dtfim[] = datafim.split("/");
        String diaf = dtfim[0];
        String mesf = dtfim[1];
        String anof = dtfim[2];

        HashMap param = new HashMap();
        param.put("dataini",  anoi +"-"+mesi+"-"+diai + " 00:00:00" );
        param.put("datafim", anof +"-"+mesf+"-"+diaf + " 23:59:59" );

        if (tipoMov.equalsIgnoreCase("entrada")) {
            param.put("tipmov", "entrada" );
        } else if(tipoMov.equalsIgnoreCase("saida")) {
            param.put("tipmov", "saida" );
        } //else if(tipoMov.equalsIgnoreCase("entradaesaida")) {
            //param.put("tipmov", "entrada or tipo = "+'"'+"saida"+'"');
        //}

        InputStream arquivo = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/relatorios/RelMoviment.jasper");

        byte[] pdf = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(arquivo, param ,con);

        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream(); 
        out.write(pdf);
        out.flush();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@sergioBertolazzo , realmente vc está certo, mas uma coisa que eu não estava me ligando era no ! do p{}... aí nunca iria passar da maneira que eu queria ou fazer um ternário.... depois que coloquei p!{} tudo ficou legal.

Answer (score 1):

Se está tudo funcionando bem, e o erro só ocorre quando você passa os dois parâmetros, seu erro está na consulta.

Se voce olhar sua consulta esta ficando assim:

```
he.tipo = 'entrada or tipo = saida'
```

entao, basta você mudar seu parametro de:

```
param.put("tipmov", "entrada or tipo = "+'"'+"saida"+'"');
```

para:

```
param.put("tipmov", "entrada or he.tipo = "+'"'+"saida"+'"');
```